# Rails: Lazy_high_charts mapping issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am not seeing any data on my chart: Highcharts using Laz_highcharts

```
 @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
 f.title(:text => 'Rate')
 f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime',
        :title => {
          text: 'Day'
        })
 f.yAxis(:title => {
          text: 'Price'
        })
 f.series(:name => 'Price',
         :data => Rate.usdzar
                    .map { |i| [i.day.to_time.to_i,
                                i.price] })

   f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
   end
```

When I view the html I see the data but it doesn't show on the page
Any assistance is great full

The data format:

```
    (function() {

      var onload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function(){
        if (typeof onload == "function") onload();
                var options = { "title": { "text": "Rate" },"legend": 
{ "layout": "vertical","style": {  } },"xAxis": { "type": 
"datetime","title": { "text": "Day" } },"yAxis": { "title": { "text": 
"Price" } },"tooltip": { "enabled": true },"credits": { "enabled": 
false },"plotOptions": { "areaspline": {  } },"chart": { 
"defaultSeriesType": "line","renderTo": "my_id" },"subtitle": {  
},"series": [{ "name": "Price","data": [ [ 1449007200,"14.31" ],[ 
1449093600,"14.25" ],[ 1450044000,"15.02" ],[ 1450130400,"14.86" ],[ 
1449180000,"14.27" ],[ 1449439200,"14.32" ],[ 1449525600,"14.49" ],[ 
1449612000,"14.52" ],[ 1449698400,"14.85" ],[ 1449784800,"15.36" ],[ 
1450303200,"14.85" ],[ 1450389600,"14.98" ],[ 1450648800,"14.93" ],[ 
1450735200,"15.04" ],[  1459202400,"15.37" ],[ 1459288800,"14.81" ],[ 
1459375200,"14.65" ],[ 1475100000,"13.59" ],[ 1475186400,"13.59" ],[ 
1475445600,"13.55" ],[ 1475532000,"13.59" ],[ 1475618400,"13.69" ],[ 
1475704800,"13.72" ],[ 1479852000,"14.01" ],[ 1479938400,"14.08" ],[ 
1480024800,"14.03" ],[ 1480284000,"13.79" ],[ 1480370400,"13.69" ],[ 
1480456800,"13.7" ],[  ] ] }] };`

    window.chart_my_id = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

      };
            })()
```

Thanks for the help thus far

The latest controller: seeing the data perfectly but date formatting is not showing correctly. The data issue was fixed by to_f on price and adding DollarChills suggestion to seperate x and y axis. The UTC date is somehow not readable from my data that is stored as as "2017-09-21".

```
@u = Rate.usdzar.last(60)
@rd = Rate.select(:day).order(:id).last(60)
x_axis_start = @rd.first.day


@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
f.title(:text => 'Rates')
f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', :day => @rd.map { |i| i.day.to_datetime.to_i }, :title => { text: 'Days' }, pointStart: x_axis_start.to_datetime.to_i)
f.yAxis(:title => { text: 'Price' })
f.series(:name => 'Price', :data => @u.map { |i| i.price.to_f })
f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
```

end

The to_time.to_i * 1000, I have tried but with the same result
The actual source shows it in miliseconds but still gives the first on X-axis as 1-Jan and rest as 00:00:00 010 - 00:00:00 050

The code run is:

```
@u = Rate.usdzar.last(60)
@rd = Rate.select(:day).order(:id).last(60)
x_axis_start = @rd.first.day


@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => 'Rates')
  f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', :day => @rd.map { |i| i.day.to_time.to_i * 1000 }, :title => { text: 'Days' }, pointStart: x_axis_start.to_time.to_i * 1000)
  f.yAxis(:title => { text: 'Price' })
  f.series(:name => 'Price', :data => @u.map { |i| i.price.to_f })
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
end
```

The source of the page:

```
    (function() {

      var onload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function(){
        if (typeof onload == "function") onload();
                var options = { "title": { "text": "Rates" },"legend": { "layout": "vertical","style": {  } },"xAxis": { "type": "datetime","day": [ 1504648800000,1504648800000,1504648800000,1504648800000,1504648800000,1504735200000,1504735200000,1504735200000,1504735200000,1504735200000,1504821600000,1504821600000,1504821600000,1504821600000,1504821600000,1505167200000,1505167200000,1505167200000,1505167200000,1505167200000,1505253600000,1505253600000,1505253600000,1505253600000,1505253600000,1505340000000,1505340000000,1505340000000,1505340000000,1505340000000,1505426400000,1505426400000,1505426400000,1505426400000,1505426400000,1505685600000,1505685600000,1505685600000,1505685600000,1505685600000,1505772000000,1505772000000,1505772000000,1505772000000,1505772000000,1505858400000,1505858400000,1505858400000,1505858400000,1505858400000,1505944800000,1505944800000,1505944800000,1505944800000,1505944800000,1506031200000,1506031200000,1506031200000,1506031200000,1506031200000 ],"title": { "text": "Days" },"pointStart": Date.UTC(4.748310497088e+19, 3.9000496896e+18, 1.3000165632e+17) },"yAxis": { "title": { "text": "Price" } },"tooltip": { "enabled": true },"credits": { "enabled": false },"plotOptions": { "areaspline": {  } },"chart": { "defaultSeriesType": "line","renderTo": "my_id" },"subtitle": {  },"series": [{ "name": "Price","data": [ 12.82,12.8,12.93,12.87,12.99,13.15,13.15,13.35,13.31,13.28,13.44,13.25,13.14,12.99,12.92,12.88,12.89,12.93,12.87,12.88,12.92,13.02,12.86,12.99,12.97,12.97,13.23,13.2,13.3,13.11,13.31,13.42,13.32,13.28,13.19,13.12,13.19,13.16,13.13,13.19,13.15,13.02,13.01,12.94,12.97,12.99,12.85,12.94,12.82,12.77,12.75,12.87,12.97,13.1,13.11,13.13,13.26,13.22,13.25,13.16 ] }] };

    window.chart_my_id = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

      };
            })()
```

The erb:

```
<%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>
```

This looks correct but obviously still something adrift
Thanks for the reply, still at a loss.

Comment: When you say you can 'view the html I see the data but it doesn't show on the page', do you mean the graph doesn't show? Can you add your view.html.erb?

Comment: <%= high_chart("my_id", @chart) %> This is my erb. The graph is absolutely blank. I have tried with other static data and it works so I do think its got to do with the wat I am sending the data. Thanks for the assistance. The data shown above is the page source but its not being presented on the page/graph.

Comment: It may have something to do with your data. I just tried the above code with static data and it worked fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this. Moving the date to the x-axis. I think it isn't plotting because no x-axis has been given.

```
@chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
 f.title(:text => 'Rate')
 f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', :categories => Rate.usdzar.map { |i| i.day.to_time.to_i}, :title => { text: 'Day' })
 f.yAxis(:title => { text: 'Price' })
 f.series(:name => 'Price', :data => Rate.usdzar.map { |i| i.price })
 f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
end
```

Comment: thanks its now plotting the y axis data perfectly but the formatting of the dates (days) I have been struggling with. Tried .to_datetime and to_date and even tried to set a startPoint in options but still renders: first is 1Jan then 00:00:00 010 to 00:00:00:020. THANKS for the help

Comment: For the time stamp try. Rate.usdzar.map { |i| i.day.to_time.to_i * 1000}

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this working for those interested the final code:

Controller

```
@ih = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(:text => 'Rates-USDZAR')
  f.xAxis(:type => 'datetime', :title => { text: 'Days' })
  f.yAxis(:title => {text: 'Price'})
  f.series(:name => 'USDZAR', :data => Rate.usdzar.last(60).map { |i| 
  [i.day.to_time.to_i * 1000, i.price.to_f ] })
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType => 'line'})
end

@chart_globals = LazyHighCharts::HighChartGlobals.new do |f|
  f.global(useUTC: false)
  f.chart(backgroundColor: {linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],stops:
  [[0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],[1, "rgb(240, 240, 255)"]]},
  borderWidth: 2,
  plotBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)",
  plotShadow: true,
  plotBorderWidth: 1)
  f.lang(thousandsSep: ",")
  f.colors(["#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", "#f15c80", "#e4d354"])
end
```

ERB:

```
<%= high_chart("my_id", @ih) %>
```

Thanks for all input: must say I think doing this raw highcharts would be better but I still am having issues mapping..but it works. I have also got Chartkick working but prefer LHCharts, it for me seems more understandable.